Async tasks: is there a short-circuiting TrueForAll() method or pattern?
I've got a list of tasks that check conditions, returning true or false values.
public override async Task<TradeEntry?> TryGetNewTradeEntryAsync(RequestNewTradeEntry request)
{
    if (await condition.FalseAsync<IsPeriodEnd>
        (new(request, this.Settings.PeriodGap, this.productCode)))
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (await condition.FalseAsync<EventActiveWithAvailableEntries>
        (new(request, this.productCode, this)))
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (await condition.FalseAsync<IsAfterNewsEvent>
        (new(request, 1, this.Period1m, this.productCode)))
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (await condition.TrueAsync<AfterNewsClosedOverExtremeSwingPointBeforeNews>
        (new(request, this.Settings.SwingPointLookback, request.Bias.Opposite(), this.Period1m, this.productCode)))
    {
        // find a gap...
    }
    else if (await condition.TrueAsync<HasNoUnclosedOverSwingPointBeforeNews>
        (new(request, this.Settings.SwingPointLookback, request.Bias.Opposite(), this.Period1m, this.productCode)))
    {
        // look for new swing points closed over...
    }
}

In many cases, I don't necessarily need them to run sequentially.
I might just want to return null as soon as a single task returns false, for example, and skip checks on the other conditions.
The assumption here is that I don't want to assume which tasks run faster - some might complete instantly, some might take quite some time to complete if they need to query a database or file, for example.
This implementation has and will continue to change frequently, and I don't want to be constantly updating this code to try and optimize the check order (these types of checks will be repeated in hundreds of classes).
Is there a way to accomplish this? For example, something like Task.TrueForAll(...) that cancels the other tasks once any task returns false?
Returning early is important since I'm running this approximately 35 million times in a loop, and don't want to waste time checking conditions that don't need to be checked.
Thanks!

Task.WhenAny Method - literally the top search result for just "whenany".

But I'd combine this with a cancelation token. Otherwise you are bound to congest the thread pool.

Another alternative could be to not parallelize but pipeline. Rx or maybe Dataflow come to my mind.

@Fildor I phrased the WhenAny() part poorly (will update the question now) - WhenAny just returns once any task completes as I understand, but I'd be interested in knowing once a task completes with a false return, and cancelling the others after that.
What I'm really looking for is something like a Task.TrueForAll(...)

Then definitely look into Dataflow and consider pipelining. I'm on the cell phone rn but later I can maybe scribble an example ...

You probably want to process every task immediately as it completes. S.Toub once wrote article describing how this pattern might be implemented. You might want to reuse last code sample - Interleaved method - mentioned there, unless you already use .NET9 - it has remake of this feature built-in. The method needs some refactoring, though.

@Ryan do you mean the new "WhenEach"?

@Filder, yep, exactly. Consumer would be able to iterate through tasks in their chronological order, and break out of the iteration when needed.

Related: How to implement Task.WhenAny() with a predicate.

@TheodorZoulias Understood, removed.

Upcoming features of the dotnet sdk will probably make this obsolete and it's not a Task.WhenAny( Predicate ) but this would be my approach to the underlying problem you want to solve.
The idea is to not parallelize all condition checks for each item but to create a pipeline consisting of one step for each condition. If one condition does not hold it will bail out and not perform the succeeding steps for the respective item.
The benefits I would assume are:

you have the desired "bail-out" behavior
each condition will be checked concurrently - just not for the same item at once
if some steps are slower than others, you can increase / decrease the parallelizm on a per-condition level
you could also optimize the order of executed checks. If one is far more likely to fail -> put it to the front of the pipeline with approx. only 3 lines of code to change.
you can increase/decrease overall parallizm as wanted or needed as long as possible.
no tons of started-and-canceled Tasks. (Of which I don't really know if that hurts, but it kind of disturbs my inner Monk.)

Fiddle
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using Bogus;
                    
public class Program
{
    //Driver for the example
    public static async Task Main()
    {

// Setting up example input data
        var settingsIds = 0;
        Faker<ThePipeline.Settings> settingsFaker = new Faker<ThePipeline.Settings>()
            .CustomInstantiator(f => new  ThePipeline.Settings(settingsIds++, f.Name.FullName(), f.Random.Bool()));
        
        var p = new ThePipeline();
        
// This is where your desired output will emerge:
        using var goodSub = p.Good.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("[GOOD]  : {0}", s));
// And this is where the garbage will be disposed:
        using var badSub = p.Bad.Subscribe(s =>   Console.WriteLine("[BAD]   : {0}", s));
        using var errSub = p.Error.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] : {0}", s));
        
// Create some example inputs and feed the pipeline
        using var pipeSub = Observable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => settingsFaker.Generate()).Subscribe(p.Input);
        
// wait for the pipeline to do its work to completion
        await p.Completion;
    }
}

// Processing pipeline
public class ThePipeline
{

// Each condition will be abstracted in a Transformblock from DataFlow
    private TransformBlock<Settings, StageResult> _stage1;
// You can start with parallelism set to 1 for all, than analyze where you have 
// backpressure or near-starvation and adapt accordingly.
    private ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions _stage1Options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
    };
    
    private TransformBlock<StageResult, StageResult> _stage2;
    private ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions _stage2Options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
    };
    

// Just to gather outpu
    private TransformBlock<StageResult, string> _theGood;
// Maybe you don't need these at all, maybe this can be one ...
    private TransformBlock<StageResult, string> _theBad;
    private TransformBlock<StageResult, string> _theUgly;
    
    public ThePipeline() 
    {
        
        var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions()
        {
            PropagateCompletion = true
        };
        
        _theGood = new TransformBlock<StageResult, string>(o => o.ToString());
        _theBad = new TransformBlock<StageResult, string>(o => o.ToString());
        _theUgly = new TransformBlock<StageResult, string>(o => o.ToString());
        
        _stage1 = new TransformBlock<Settings, StageResult>(StageOneAsync, _stage1Options);
        _stage2 = new TransformBlock<StageResult, StageResult>(StageTwoAsync, _stage2Options);
        
// Sad path: Link error / fail to "bail out" for later inspection?
// If not interested, just use a NOP-ActionBlock, maybe.
        _stage1.LinkTo(_theBad, linkOptions, r => r is StageBadResult);
        _stage1.LinkTo(_theUgly, linkOptions, r => r is StageUglyResult);
        
        _stage2.LinkTo(_theBad, linkOptions, r => r is StageBadResult);
        _stage2.LinkTo(_theUgly, linkOptions, r => r is StageUglyResult);
        
// Happy path:
// Input -> condition 1 is true -> condition 2 is true -> Output
        _stage1.LinkTo(_stage2, linkOptions, r => r is StageGoodResult);
        _stage2.LinkTo(_theGood, linkOptions, r => r is StageGoodResult);
    }
    
// We need to await the pipeline to run until empty.
    public Task Completion => Task.WhenAll(_theGood.Completion, _theBad.Completion, _theUgly.Completion);

// For ease of use -> Reactive input / output. You can use other APIs, of course.
    public IObserver<Settings> Input => _stage1.AsObserver();
    
    public IObservable<string> Good => _theGood.AsObservable();
    public IObservable<string> Bad => _theBad.AsObservable();
    public IObservable<string> Error => _theUgly.AsObservable();
    
// Implementation for each "condition" to check.
    private async Task<StageResult> StageOneAsync(Settings s)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(100); // "Do some work"
            return await RandomizeReturn(s, 1);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new StageUglyResult(s, 1, ex.Message );
        }
    }
    
    private async Task<StageResult> StageTwoAsync(StageResult s)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(200); // "Do some slightly heavier work"
            return await RandomizeReturn(s.Settings, 2);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new StageUglyResult(s.Settings, 2,  ex.Message );
        }
    }
    
    private Task<StageResult> RandomizeReturn(Settings s, int stage)
    {
        return Random.Shared.Next(100) switch
        {
                < 10 => throw new ApplicationException("Naw, that's ugly!"),
                < 30 => Task.FromResult(new StageBadResult(s, stage) as StageResult),
                _ => Task.FromResult(new StageGoodResult(s, stage) as StageResult)
        };
    }
    
// Just some sort of input -- adapt for your situation
    public record Settings(int Id, string Name, bool IsSomething );
// Internal result - objects to do the routing.
    private record StageResult ( Settings Settings, int Stage );
    private record StageGoodResult ( Settings Settings, int Stage ) : StageResult ( Settings, Stage );
    private record StageBadResult ( Settings Settings, int Stage ) : StageResult ( Settings, Stage );
    private record StageUglyResult ( Settings Settings, int Stage, string Error ) : StageResult ( Settings, Stage );
}


When moving on to .Net 9, it could also be worthwhile to have a look at Task.WhenEach.

Thank you! Reading this, I'm realizing I have a lot to learn to understand, but now I've got something for a starting point
